# How Do I Solve TypeError: validateSchema is not a function for a React App?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, package.json

It has been a while since I messed with webpack and now I'm running into some issues. when i run 'webpack --watch' or just 'webpack' i get this:

```
TypeError: validateSchema is not a function
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
 output: {
  filename: "static/bundle.js"
},
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    include: /app/,
    loader: "babel-loader",
    query: {
      presets: ['env','react']
    }
   }
  ]
 },
 devtool: "eval-source-map"
 };
```

and here is my package.json:

```
    {
     "name": "react-base",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "A MERN app skeleton",
     "main": "server.js",
     "scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
     },
     "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git+https://github.com/marcodarko/react-base.git"
  },
  "author": "Marco Cano",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/marcodarko/react-base/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/marcodarko/react-base#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "request": "^2.87.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^1.15.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-command": "^0.4.1"
  }
}
```

npm start works fine and express loads but my react code won't load at all.
I'm currently looking at solutions on my own but thought I would post this to the community to see if there's someone out there that knows what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "1.15.0",//removed the carat sign to use exact version
    "webpack-cli": "3.0.8",
    "webpack-command": "0.4.1"
  }
```

The changes done is to provide the exact version of webpack as including a carat sign will automatically resolve the webpack to the mentioned version or above which creates a problem because the build system keeps on changing within the webpack each time a new version is delivered .This could introduce breaking changes to the currently building application

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @jaySf - thanks for pointing that out i missed submitting the explanation on this one .Edited with the explanation now